# How to JUnit for method which is static and returns void

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

How do I write JUnit for the below method?

```
public static void invokeAuditService(HttpServletRequest request, Date serviceCallTime, String response, 
            String activityKey, JSONObject detailsReplaceVal, String pmAccountId){
        AuditLogUtils.invokeAuditService(request, serviceCallTime, response, activityKey, detailsReplaceVal,  pmAccountId);
}
```

My code:

```
@Test
public void testInvokeAuditService() {
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(WidgetHelper.class);
    WidgetHelper.invokeAuditService(Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject(), 
            Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyObject());
}
```

I am getting compiler error:
***The method invokeAuditService(HttpServletRequest, Date, String, String, JSONObject, String) in the type WidgetHelper is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object)***

Updated code:

```
@Test
    public void testInvokeAuditService() {
        
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(WidgetHelper.class);
        WidgetHelper.invokeAuditService(servletRequest, date, "abc", "xyz",json, 
                "123");
        
        verifyStatic(WidgetHelper.class, Mockito.times(1));
        WidgetHelper.invokeAuditService(servletRequest, date, "abc", "xyz",json, 
                "123");
    }
```

This says : "Actually there were zero interactions with this mock" for the line after verifystatic.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing all the values as `Object` in `invokeAuditService` method parameter. So you are getting this compiler error.

**For example**, you should pass the value of `serviceCallTime, response, activityKey, detailsReplaceVal, pmAccountId`

If you are not having value for all the parameters send the value as `null` value, but the `null` value should be handle in `invokeAuditService` method to avoid `NullpointerException`.

**change the code like below**

```
@Test
public void testInvokeAuditService() {
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(WidgetHelper.class);
    WidgetHelper.invokeAuditService(null, null, null, null, null, null);    
}
```

Now your compiler error will resolve and maybe you will face `NullpointerException` in runtime

Comment: i cannot pass null. What can I pass as parameters which actually mocks the parameters?

Comment: You shouldn't pass null, you should pass the actual value in the parmeter which required.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
@Test
    public void testInvokeAuditServiceWithSuccessFlagAndResponse() {
        
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(WidgetHelper.class);
        WidgetHelper.invokeAuditService(servletRequest, date, "abc", json, 
                "123", "Y");
        
        verifyStatic(WidgetHelper.class, Mockito.times(1));
    }
```

I was actually asking Mockito to verify an interaction before the interaction has occurred.